Odd perfect numbers equal one modulo four
I use perfect numbers in same sense as this wiki.

Conjecture: A odd perfect number mod 4 is 1

So far I got to the following facts.

Through the fact that it's odd, we can find that:
1.1. It must be either 1 or 3 mod 4
1.2. All of its factors are odd.

If we prime factorize it as $n= \prod p_i^{\alpha_i}$ then it must be that the total number of $p_i$ which are 1 mod 4 plus the number of $p_i$ which are $3 mod 4$ is an odd number.  This follows from it being an odd perfect number.


Now, I am having difficulties proceeding further. I am guessing, we have to use the fact that it's perfect number again and consider the sum of its divisors mod 4.

Hint: If $n\equiv 3\pmod 4$ then $n$ is not a square, and the pairs of divisors $d,n/d$ add up to a multiiple of four, so $\sum_{d\mid n} d$ is a multiple of $4, so can't be 2n.$

If $n\equiv 3\pmod 4$ then $d,n/d$ are distinct factors for each $d\mid n,$ and $d+\frac nd$ is a multiple of $4.$
So $\sigma(n)=\sum_{d\mid n} d$ is a multiple of $4,$ and $2n\equiv 2\pmod 4,$ so $\sigma(n)\neq 2n.$

Longer form:
$n$ isn't a square, so $d^2\neq n$ for any $d\mid n.$
$$\sum_{d\mid n} d =\sum_{d\mid n, d^2<n} d+\sum_{d\mid n, d^2>n} d\\
=\sum_{d\mid n, d^2<n} d+\sum_{d\mid n, d^2<n} \frac nd\\
=\sum_{d\min n, d^2<n}\left(d+\frac nd\right)$$
I'll leave to you why each $d+\frac nd$ is a multiple of $4.$

Even more generally, if $n$ is an odd perfect number then $n=n_0n_1^2$ for some $n_0,n_1$ where $n_0$ is only divisible by primes $p\equiv 1\pmod 4.$
This is because if $n=p_1^{a_1}\cdots p_k^{a_k}$ then $\sigma(n)=\prod_i \sigma(p_i^{a_i}),$ and $\sigma(p^a)$ is a multiple of four when $p^a\equiv 3\pmod 4,$ that is, when $p\equiv 3$ and $a$ is odd. So every $p_i^{a_i}\equiv 1\pmod 4.$
This condition is equivalent to $n$ being expressible as the sum of two squares.

How does mod 3 led to d and n/d being distinct factors?

Because $n\equiv 3\pmod4$ means $n$ is not a square. @trystwithfreedom

Why did you split the sum along those numbers whose square are less than $n$ and those whose squares are greater than $n$? Rest is clear

Because in any factoring  $d_1d_2=n,$ exactly one $d_i^2<n$ and the other is $d_j^2>n.$ @trystwithfreedom

Expanding Thomas Andrews answer.

If $n = 3  \mod 4 $ then factors are distinct.

Any divisor of a number has a property that $\frac{n}{d}$ is also a divisor.

If it are to be the case that these two are equal for some divisor, that is $d=\frac{n}{d}$ then $n$ is a perfect square. Note that the divisors $1$ and $n$ itself are excluded for obvious reasons.

If it is the case that $n$ is a perfect square, we have a contradiction, as perfect squares can only be $1$ or $0$ modulo $4$



$d+ \frac{d}{n} \mod 4$  if $n=3 \mod 4$

Since $n$ is an odd number, all of it's factors must be odd. In modulo $4$ this means that they are either $1$ or $3$
We have that $d* \frac{d}{n} = n$, taking $\mod 4$, we have $ (d \mod 4) * ( \frac{d}{n} \mod 4)  = n \mod 4 =3$
We have that $$ (1 \mod 4) * (1 \mod 4)= 1  \mod 4$$ $$(3 \mod 4) * (3 \mod 4)=1  \mod 4$$ and $$(3 \mod 4) * (1 \mod 4) = 3 \mod 4$$

As can be seen, the only way that the odd factors can multiply into a three is if one of then is $1 \mod 4$ and the other $ 3 \mod 4$. But, if they are so, then they add to $ 4 \mod 4$ which is a zero.

